# Why does SQL Server not evaluate -1 as True in a bit column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I ran a query looking for records `WHERE Column1 = -1`  (looking for True values in a `bit` column). When I look at the table in SSMS I see plenty of records displayed with -1 values. When I query the table as a linked table in MS Access I have to change the WHERE clause to `Column1 = 1` because `Column1 = -1` doesn't return the rows where they say -1 in SSMS.

*Very weird!*

In MS Access I've always used -1 to get True values in a Boolean column. Can anyone explain? I haven't seen this documented anywhere.

Comment: Open up the linked table and see whether the column type is yes/no. If it's a Boolean column you will see -1. If it's a number, 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ANY non-zero value becomes 1. Here is mention of this in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql

Comment: To add to this, there are no rows in your sql server table that have a bit column with a value of -1. There are three and only three values for a bit column in sql server (0, 1, NULL).

Comment: Thanks, Sean! Appreciate the quick response, too!

Answer (score 1):

There's some transition between MS Access bit and ODBC sql_bit datatypes. In T-SQL, converting any non-zero value to bit turns it into 1.  So -1 becomes 1, or 27 becomes 1, or whatever.  So I suspect that the conversion through ODBC data types is causing this.